# Nginx: proxx_pass to upstream(xxxx:8080) , but always redirect to 80 Port?

Tags: nginx

i am almost a fresher to StackOverflow, I thinks i made a clear & well understand title now :)

my original server can access at : localhost:8080. and now i made a nginx proxy which will be accessed from [IP_ADDr]:8088 from outside. But the result it will always redirect my url to [IP_ADDr]:80 that the 404 page present.
below is the config file:

```
 upstream  manage_addr  {
      server   127.0.0.1:8080;
      keepalive 16;
 }

 server {
     listen       8088;
     location / {
        include proxy-opt.conf;
       proxy_pass http://manage_addr;
                access_log  /var/log/nginx/access_log_proxy_http.log;  
        #root   /etc/nginx;
        #index  index.html index.htm;
     }
 }
```

below is proxy-opt.conf:

```
    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_connect_timeout   30;
    proxy_send_timeout      30;
    proxy_read_timeout      60;
    proxy_buffer_size       4k;
    proxy_buffers           4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_503 http_404;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
```

I found the issue may related with proxy-opt.conf.

Comment: Why do you think that nginx redirects to :80? You have another site at port 80 and 404 page comes from here?

Comment: Because the url in browser is redirected to [IP_Addr]:80.. and i found the access log in Nginx mentions the 302 redirect http code.

Comment: If i access the  [IP_Addr]:80, then the welcome of Nginx page will present.

Comment: Most likely you have other vhost configs which listen to port 80 or perhaps your main Nginx.conf has a redirection

Comment: [ip_address]:80 , it always show : "Welcome to nginx!" welcome page. how to remove it , i am using Nginx nginx version: nginx/1.9.15 which can not find the